# How to wipe out core data content on update?

Tags: ios, core-data

In my current project I use core data to store information. Now I need to update my phone app and data model slightly changed. I wonder if I am going to take some action to delete old data on devices? Or is this process automatic?

Comment: Have you tried reading up on model migration? Core data can automatically migrate your data to the new database for you, you really shouldn't have to delete everything

Comment: See this https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=model+migration+core+data&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do for lightweight migration which is suitable in most cases.

1. Create a new model version
2. Make your changes
3. Make the new model version the active one.
4. Add these the two options below when you add your persistent store

And you are all set.

```
@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
  NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES}
```

The existing data is now preserved. This is all very well [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1), so please do your research before asking follow-up questions.

If, on the other hand, you want to "wipe" all the old data (if you are sure that is what your users want), you can simply delete the persistent store with `NSFileManager` before adding it to the persistent store coordinator.